# Multiple usage of same formula in SELECT fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query where I calculate value for WorkingTime as follows:

```
 SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.Type = 1
                THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(s,
                                ca.StartTime,
                                ca.EndTime) AS FLOAT)
                    / 60.0
                ELSE NULL
        END) AS WorkingTime ,
    AnnotherResult ...
```

The value of AnotherResult is also calculated with some equation, and in this equation I need to use WorkingTime.

Do I need to repeat the SUM (CASE ....) which is used to calculate WorkingTime everywhere I require it, or I can somehow refer directly to WorkingTime value in subsequent field value calculation?

Comment: You have to repeat it.

Comment: You could wrap it in a subquery and then make multiple references to the computed value in the top level query.

Comment: You could create an SQL function, passing in the parameters for the equation each time. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax

```
Select ... , something/WorkingTime, something*WorkingTime, ...
From
(
Select *, CASE WHEN a.Type = 1
                THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(s,
                                ca.StartTime,
                                ca.EndTime) AS FLOAT)
                    / 60.0
                ELSE NULL
        END) AS WorkingTime 
from myTable
) t
```

now you can use workingtime in other parts of query

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options, the most common are

1. Derived table
2. CTE

---

```
SELECT WorkingTime
    FROM (
           SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN a.Type = 1 THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(s, ca.StartTime, ca.EndTime) AS FLOAT) / 60.0
                           ELSE NULL
                      END) AS WorkingTime .....)
```

---

```
;WITH WT AS (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN a.Type = 1 THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(s, ca.StartTime, ca.EndTime) AS FLOAT) / 60.0
                               ELSE NULL
                          END) AS WorkingTime .....)
SELECT WorkingTime
FROM WT
JOIN .....
```

Comment: Technically #1 is a derived table, not a subquery.

Comment: Corrected the terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers cover some of these items (derived table, common table expression), but I wanted to pull it together into a single answer with executable code, as well as providing a few additional alternatives (cross apply, CLR SQL Server Aggregate).

First, I will address the comment suggesting a user-defined function. You could certainly encapsulate the CASE statement and its calculation into a user-defined function. I would suggest an inline table-valued function, which would be fed the start time, end time, and type. It would be a pure calculation, and it would be deterministic. It would have no negative impact on performance and it would encapsulate code for re-use. This would *not* be an aggregate function; the aggregation would still occur on its results. See Method #4 in the code sample to see how it would be consumed.

Another user-defined function option would be to create an inline table-valued user-defined function which contained the base aggregation. You would start your query by using that function, and then its results could be used in additional calculations. See Method #5 in the code sample to see how it would be consumed. However, if you have more complex logic and avoiding code repetition is important, you will still end up using one of the other methods (CTE, derived table) in the function itself, or you will have to layer multiple user-defined functions to perform successive, stacked computations.

Other options for user-defined (native SQL) functions (scalar, multi-statement table-valued) are not recommended as they have often significant performance penalties.

Another function option is to create a [CLR SQL Server Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91e6taax%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). SQL Server essentially passes the column of data out to as assembly running on the server (outside of SQL Server), which assembly performs the calculations and makes the results accessible to SQL Server for the rest of the query. Some DBAs discourage use of CLR functions because it adds some minor server management overhead and security considerations.

Pure SQL (no function creation required) methods include using derived tables or common table expressions (CTEs). CTEs are essentially derived tables which can be re-used multiple times in a statement, so they are generally more flexible than derived tables. However, they are not available prior to SQL Server 2005. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22964913/2266979) provided a derived table solution but referred to it as a "subquery". Technically, [a derived table is not a subquery](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/derived-table-vs-subquery/). A [subquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is generally when an entire SQL statement is used to return a single value which is used elsewhere in the statement. A [derived table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) is a separate SELECT statement which generates a set of values and is used as a "virtual table" within the rest of the statement.

It's worth noting that the derived table (#2 below) and CTE methods (#1 below) offer a little better code reduction than the APPLY method (#3 below), because the APPLY method merely encapsulates the calculation, not the aggregation. Aggregation sort of "takes over" a query, so in order to use those aggregated results, you must encapsulate them into a CTE or derived table.

In my testing on SQL Server 2005, the first three "pure SQL" methods all generated identical query plans, so the choice of method is largely about syntactical preferences and not performance.

```
DECLARE @CA TABLE
(
    StartTime datetime,
    EndTime datetime,
    ActivityType int,
    Employee varchar(50)
);
INSERT INTO @CA (StartTime, EndTime, ActivityType, Employee) VALUES ('2014-04-01 1:00 PM', '2014-04-01 2:00 PM', 1, 'Jim');
INSERT INTO @CA (StartTime, EndTime, ActivityType, Employee) VALUES ('2014-04-03 1:00 PM', '2014-04-03 3:00 PM', 1, 'Jim');
INSERT INTO @CA (StartTime, EndTime, ActivityType, Employee) VALUES ('2014-04-04 9:00 AM', '2014-04-04 11:00 AM', 1, 'Jim');
INSERT INTO @CA (StartTime, EndTime, ActivityType, Employee) VALUES ('2014-04-05 10:00 AM', '2014-04-04 11:13 AM', 0, 'Jim');
INSERT INTO @CA (StartTime, EndTime, ActivityType, Employee) VALUES ('2014-04-02 10:00 AM', '2014-04-02 3:00 PM', 1, 'Sally');
INSERT INTO @CA (StartTime, EndTime, ActivityType, Employee) VALUES ('2014-04-04 1:55 PM', '2014-04-04 3:11 PM', 1, 'Sally');
INSERT INTO @CA (StartTime, EndTime, ActivityType, Employee) VALUES ('2014-03-30 1:45 PM', '2014-04-01 1:00 AM', 0, 'Sally');

-- Method #1: CTE

WITH BaseData AS
(
    SELECT
        Employee,
        SUM (
                CASE
                    WHEN ca.ActivityType = 1 THEN
                        1
                    ELSE
                        0
                END
            ) AS NumType1Entries,
        SUM (
                CASE
                    WHEN ca.ActivityType = 1 THEN
                        CAST(DATEDIFF(s, ca.StartTime, ca.EndTime) AS FLOAT) / 60.0
                    ELSE
                        NULL
                END
            ) AS TotalMinutesType1
    FROM        @CA ca
    GROUP BY    Employee
)
SELECT
    BaseData.Employee,
    BaseData.NumType1Entries,
    BaseData.TotalMinutesType1,
    CASE
        WHEN BaseData.NumType1Entries > 0 THEN
            BaseData.TotalMinutesType1 / BaseData.NumType1Entries
        ELSE
            NULL
    END AS MinutesPerType1Entry
FROM        BaseData;

-- Method #2: Derived Table

SELECT
    BaseData.Employee,
    BaseData.NumType1Entries,
    BaseData.TotalMinutesType1,
    CASE
        WHEN BaseData.NumType1Entries > 0 THEN
            BaseData.TotalMinutesType1 / BaseData.NumType1Entries
        ELSE
            NULL
    END AS MinutesPerType1Entry
FROM        (
                SELECT
                    Employee,
                    SUM (
                            CASE
                                WHEN ca.ActivityType = 1 THEN
                                    1
                                ELSE
                                    0
                            END
                        ) AS NumType1Entries,
                    SUM (
                            CASE
                                WHEN ca.ActivityType = 1 THEN
                                    CAST(DATEDIFF(s, ca.StartTime, ca.EndTime) AS FLOAT) / 60.0
                                ELSE
                                    NULL
                            END
                        ) AS TotalMinutesType1
                FROM @CA ca
                GROUP BY Employee
            ) AS BaseData;

-- Method #3 - Cross Apply

SELECT
    Employee,
    SUM (Calcs.Type1EntryCounter) AS NumType1Entries,
    SUM (Calcs.Type1EntryTotalMinutes) AS TotalMinutesType1,
    CASE
        WHEN SUM (Type1EntryCounter) > 0 THEN
            SUM (Type1EntryTotalMinutes) / SUM (Type1EntryCounter)
        ELSE
            NULL
    END AS MinutesPerType1Entry
FROM        @CA ca
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT
                    CASE
                        WHEN ca.ActivityType = 1 THEN
                            1
                        ELSE
                            0
                    END AS Type1EntryCounter,
                    CASE
                        WHEN ca.ActivityType = 1 THEN
                            CAST(DATEDIFF(s, ca.StartTime, ca.EndTime) AS FLOAT) / 60.0
                        ELSE
                            NULL
                    END AS Type1EntryTotalMinutes
            ) AS Calcs
GROUP BY    Employee;

-- Method #4 - Inline Table-Valued User-Defined Function, Deterministic

-- Commented-out because it can't be run without creating the function first.

/*

SELECT
    Employee,
    SUM (Calcs.Type1EntryCounter) AS NumType1Entries,
    SUM (Calcs.Type1EntryTotalMinutes) AS TotalMinutesType1,
    CASE
        WHEN SUM (Type1EntryCounter) > 0 THEN
            SUM (Type1EntryTotalMinutes) / SUM (Type1EntryCounter)
        ELSE
            NULL
    END AS MinutesPerType1Entry
FROM        @CA ca
CROSS APPLY dbo.CalcType1Statistics
            (
                ca.ActivityType,
                ca.StartTime,
                ca.EndTime
            ) AS Calcs
GROUP BY    Employee;

*/

-- Method #5 - Inline Table-Valued User-Defined Function, Non-Deterministic Aggregation

-- Commented-out because it can't be run without creating the function first.
/*

SELECT
    EmpSummary.Employee,
    EmpSummary.NumType1Entries,
    EmpSummary.TotalMinutesType1,
    CASE
        WHEN EmpSummary.NumType1Entries THEN
            EmpSummary.TotalMinutesType1 / EmpSummary.NumType1Entries
        ELSE
            NULL
    END AS MinutesPerType1Entry
FROM    dbo.GetEmployeeSummary () AS EmpSummary

*/
```

P.S.:

An important limitation to derived tables is that you cannot refer to other fields in your statement within the definition of the derived table. They have to stand alone; when designing them in SSMS, you will need to be able to run them separately for them to be considered a true derived table. You can limit their results and reference other tables when you JOIN to them. If you need to have a set of values which is generated in relation to (i.e. correlated to) each row of the main SELECT, then you must use the APPLY operator.